# Create a Method to set data to the object

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

Writing a code for checking data on different conditions.
I have an ArrayList of CRM objects "actionsList" (made in another class).
Here I check these objects for different conditions.
Objects which satisfy the conditions I have to add to the ArrayList "remarksList".
The question is how to create a method setRemarkObject() to set all data to remarkObject at once?
Not to write each time:

```
  remarkObject.setRemark(checkString);
  remarkObject.setNumber(crm.getNumber());
  remarkObject.setDealer(crm.getDealer());
  remarkObject.setName(crm.getName());
```

...

is it correct now?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Conditions {

    static ArrayList<CRM> remarksList = new ArrayList<CRM>();

    public ArrayList<CRM> conditionsChecking() {
        for (CRM crm : App.actionsList) {
            CRM remarkObject = new CRM();

            remarkObject.setNumber(crm.getNumber());
            remarkObject.setDealer(crm.getDealer());
            remarkObject.setName(crm.getName());
            remarkObject.setGroup(crm.getGroup());
            remarkObject.setClientStatus(crm.getClientStatus());
            remarkObject.setEntity(crm.getEntity());
            remarkObject.setTypeOfContact(crm.getTypeOfContact());
            remarkObject.setTypeOfFirstContact(crm.getTypeOfFirstContact());
            remarkObject.setSourceOfFirstContact(crm
                    .getSourceOfFirstContact());
            remarkObject.setOfferType(crm.getOfferType());
            remarkObject.setEventDate(crm.getEventDate());
            remarkObject.setBrand(crm.getBrand());
            remarkObject.setCarClass(crm.getCarClass());
            remarkObject.setModel(crm.getModel());
            remarkObject.setCarCode(crm.getCarCode());
            remarkObject.setWeek(crm.getWeek());
            remarkObject.setMonth(crm.getMonth());
            remarkObject.setYear(crm.getYear());
            remarkObject.setAmmount(crm.getAmmount());
            remarkObject.setSalesman(crm.getSalesman());
            remarkObject.setPhone(crm.getPhone());
            remarkObject.setEmail(crm.getEmail());
            remarkObject.setAddress(crm.getAdress());
            remarkObject.setCreationDate(crm.getCreationDate());
            remarkObject.setCreationTime(crm.getCreationTime());
            remarkObject.setModificationDate(crm.getModificationDate());
            remarkObject.setModificationTime(crm.getModificationTime());
            remarkObject.setBackdating(crm.getBackdating());

            if ((crm.getClientStatus().equals("Yes")) && ((crm.getAdress().isEmpty()))){
                crm.setRemark("Client's address is empty");
            remarksList.add(remarkObject);
            }
            else if ((crm.getClientStatus().equals("Yes")) && (crm.getPhone().isEmpty())){          
                crm.setRemark( "Phone field is empty");
            remarksList.add(remarkObject);
            }
            ///....
            else
                crm.setRemark("Nothing wrong");
                /// not adding to remarksLis

        }
        return remarksList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a constructor with parameter or each Property or create a static method wich will create a new Object, call all setter and return it.

Comment: I suggest you to look at the Builder pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing the same thing over and over again, with the addition of a String which states if a field is left empty. So Why not move the setters one block up, outside of the for loop?

```
static ArrayList<CRM> remarksList = new ArrayList<CRM>();

public ArrayList<CRM> conditionsChecking() {
    for (CRM crm : App.actionsList) {
        CRM remarkObject = new CRM();

        remarkObject.setNumber(crm.getNumber());
        remarkObject.setDealer(crm.getDealer());
        remarkObject.setName(crm.getName());
        remarkObject.setGroup(crm.getGroup());
        //etcetera, etcetera, all setters, except remark

        if ((crm.getClientStatus().equals("Yes")) && ((crm.getAdress().isEmpty())))
            crm.setRemark("Client's address is empty");
        else if ((crm.getClientStatus().equals("Yes")) && (crm.getPhone().isEmpty()))            
            crm.setRemark( "Phone field is empty");
        // etc, etc
        else
            remarksList.add(remarkObject);
    }
    return remarksList;
}
```

For setters and getters in general, you can also use a constructor:

```
public CRM(String number, String dealer, String name, ...) { 
    this.number = number;
    //...etc
}
```

Or a builder

```
public CRM() {}

public CRM setNumber(String number) { 
    this.number = number;
    return this;
}

public CRM setDealer(String dealer) { 
    this.dealer = dealer;
    return this;
}

//and use it like this
CRM crm = new CRM().setNumber("123").setDealer("dealer"); //et cetera
```

Comment: Cannot move setters up because I should add to remarksList not all the objects from actionsList, but only that ones which satisfy conditions.

Comment: Or will it be correctly to add all the objects to remarksList (or even leave the actionsList itself), add conditions like if(...) {testString = "Bla bla bla";} elle {testString = null;}. And then just delete all the objects with testString = null??

Comment: @Leonid, no, see edit. I'd check if remark is set or not. `if (crm.getRemark() != null) remarksList.add(remarkObject)`

Comment: I guess I've got it. Thanks a lot. Getting your first example except one thing - will add to to remarksList just objects, satisfied if and else if

Comment: is it correct to add objects to the List in if (like I've edited), else if statements or I'd better use if (crm.getRemark() != null) remarksList.add(remarkObject)?

Comment: @Leonid if you do it in every if/ifelse, it's a few more statements. It doesnt matter all that much, though

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are copying the crm object into the remarkObject in every if-else statements. Why not copy it before all the if statements and only set the remark(checkString) inside the if-else statements? Then you can add it to remarkList after all of those statements.
You can copy the object using CRM constructor ie. CRM(CRM crm) or by cloning the object:
[How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)

Also you are checking crm.getClientStatus().equals("Yes") in every of your if statement - why not check it once at a begining?

Comment: I have got initial ArrayList "actionsList". It contains all the data from Excel file (not small). 
Here I have to put to the remarksList just incorrect statements (that not satisfy conditions.